# Mi Yodeya Chat \ Discussion room?

Tags: support, chat

This is for the moderators, is there a chat or discussion area where members of Mi Yodeya can share and exchange ideas in torah learning?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, our main chatroom is called [V'dibarta Bam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam). One way to get to it is to click on the StackExchange speech-bubble icon on the top-right of the page, and then click on "chat." Users like you with at least 100 reputation points can even [create additional chatrooms](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) for specific purposes.